# How do I properly configure glassfish 4 to work with gurobi's shared library?

Tags: glassfish, java-native-interface, gurobi

Error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/gurobi600/linux64/lib/libGurobiJni60.so: libgurobi60.so: cannot open shared object
```

It is getting the path correct when I add it via JVM settings, for some reason it doesn't find it if only relying on LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable though. Either way it has trouble with the libgurobi60.so. I tried adding all of this to glassfish_home/domains/domain1/lib/applibs and ext to no avail.

Here are the permissions for /opt/gurobi600/linux64/lib

```
-rw-r--r--  gurobi.jar          
lrwxrwxrwx  libgurobi60.so -> ./libgurobi.so.6.0.0  
lrwxrwxrwx  libgurobi_c++.a -> ./libgurobi_g++4.2.a 
-rw-r--r--  libgurobi_g++4.1.a      
-rw-r--r--  libgurobi_g++4.2.a      
-rwxr-xr-x  libGurobiJni60.so       
-rwxrwxrwx  libgurobi.so.6.0.0
```

I had this working on my previous server running ubuntu 12.04, this is now on 14.04. Previously copying the .so file to /usr/local/bin seemed to fix the issue, but this does not work on the new server.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following two commands fixed it:

```
echo "/opt/gurobi600/linux64/lib" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gurobi.conf
sudo ldconfig
```